# Mongoose : Filter an nested array for each document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
// Schema:
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  motos: [
    {
     model: { type: String }
    },
  ],
});

// Motos enabled:
  motosEnabled = [
    {
      model: 'A1',
    },
    {
      model: 'A2',
    },
  ];

User.insertMany([
  { name: 'Kartik', motos: [{ model: 'A1' }, { model: 'A3' }] },
  { name: 'Niharika', motos: [{ model: 'A1' }, { model: 'A2' }] },
])
```

I want to write a query which will return all users but filter only the motos enabled of the previous array. I'am trying to use aggregation but
I can't do it. Thanks for any help !

Output expected :

```
[
  { name: 'Kartik', motos: [{ model: 'A1' }] },
  { name: 'Niharika', motos: [{ model: 'A1' }, { model: 'A2' }] }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- you can use `$filter`
- instead of `[{"model": "A1"}, {"model": "A2"}]` put the js variable `motosEnabled`
- filter checks if the array(`motosEnabled`) contains the document `{"model" ".."}` and it passes or not

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5tUfVvFxp0B)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"motos": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$motos",
        "cond": 
         {"$in": 
           [{"model": "$$this.model"}, [{"model": "A1"}, {"model": "A2"}]]}}}}}])
```